# html middle text alignment

Tags: html, css, centering

Hey guys I am making a directory on my site and want to make the text be in the very middle not center and at not at the top I want it to be in the very middle of the document

```html
<center>
  <button href="#">Download!</button>
</center>
```

Comment: For a modern approach use flexbox.

Comment: Please add relevant code in the question. No one will dig trough your website looking at the CSS to determine what is wrong

Comment: its only html no css yet

Comment: @Ski so you didn't put any effort into finding a solution?

Comment: I did but none of them seem to work

Comment: btw thanks for your answer but it didnt work

Comment: @Ski read the following http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: aight thanks im new btw im just trying the easy stuff first such as html I put my code on btw thanks for the tips sirrr

Comment: @Ski there isn't any text or explanation of which elements you want to be centered so it's still hard to give an answer. Also notice the code mess that you have has quite a lot of syntax errors. There is also no CSS of what you have already tried

Comment: I want them all in the middle of the document and thanks for that

Comment: Like this http://joel.party/

Comment: Unclear question, the center tag is obsolete, there are multiple ways of doing it, many duplicates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give css style to your DOM

```css
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="box">
       Center
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```css
.box {
  width: var(--box-size);
  height: var(--box-size);
  line-height: var(--box-size);
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

:root {
  --box-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Center
</div>
```

Or as suggested with flexbox:

```css
.box {
  width: var(--box-size);
  height: var(--box-size);
  background: red;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

:root {
  --box-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Center
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it didnt work for me I added the div tags at the start and ended it of all my headers and paragraphs and it just went down word by word on the left

Comment: If you want a real solution add your code to the question and with CSS of what you have already tried